# Combining queries that return unequal rows into a view

Tags: sql-server

I have a database table (named: imitidx_sql) that contains a list of all of my company's 50,000+ part numbers. The column that contains this is called "item_no". I would like to create a view of the table that returns fields based on what the item number is. For instance I want a field in the view to be titled FloorAssembly and the field should contain the 100 or so item numbers like '090-40___-**'. In the next field in the view I want to return all of my two void numbers (should be about 10 or so), these numbers are like '557-05186-**'. So far I can achieve this by either using sub queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT FloorAssemblyNumber, TwoVoid, ThreeVoid

FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT item_no AS FloorAssemblyNumber
FROM imitmidx_sql
WHERE item_no LIKE '090-40___-__')
AS FloorAssemblyNumber,

(SELECT DISTINCT item_no AS TwoVoid
FROM imitmidx_sql
WHERE item_no LIKE '557-05186-__')
AS TwoVoid,

(SELECT DISTINCT item_no AS ThreeVoid
FROM imitmidx_sql
WHERE item_no LIKE '557-05128-__')
AS ThreeVoid
```

Or I can achieve the same result with the following:

```
SELECT a.item_no AS FloorAssemblyNumber, b.item_no AS TwoVoid, c.item_no AS ThreeVoid5

  FROM [002].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql]a , [002].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql]b, [002].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql]c

  WHERE a.item_no LIKE '090-40___-__' AND b.item_no LIKE '557-05186-__' AND c.item_no LIKE '557-05128-__'
```

However both of these queries seem to return all possible combinations of the individual item numbers. What I would like is to have all distinct item numbers selected and in their respective column (without any relationship to the others) and if all the necessary numbers are selected then display a null value.

Sample Data:

```
item_no
090-30811-00  
090-30812-00  
090-40000-00  
090-40000-01  
090-40000-10  
090-40000-11  
090-40000-12  
090-40001-00  
557-05186-00  
557-05186-01  
557-05186-03  
557-05187-00  
557-05200-52
```

Expected Result:

```
FloorAssembly  |  TwoVoid     
090-40000-00   |  557-05186-00             
090-40000-01   |  557-05186-01             
090-40000-10   |  557-05186-03             
090-40000-11   |              
090-40000-12   |               
090-40001-00   |
```

I apologize for the poor formatting, I am new to posting here.
Thank you for your time,

FS

Comment: better to add joining conditions to your query

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Smells like a PIVOT

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, I added some additional information per your request. Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Case statement can work for you. try this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN item_no LIKE '090-40___-__' THEN item_no ELSE NULL END AS FloorAssemblyNumber,
                CASE WHEN item_no LIKE '557-05186-__' THEN item_no ELSE NULL END AS TwoVoid,
                CASE WHEN item_no LIKE '557-05128-__' THEN item_no ELSE NULL END AS ThreeVoid
FROM imitmidx_sql
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you